# Envoy configuration locally for grpc to REST connection

Tags: rest, yaml, grpc, envoyproxy

I am not able to configure envoy.
Here is my yaml to make connection between grpc client to rest server. Grpc is in java and rest is in scala. grpc makes call to /sample endpoint.

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8080
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: backend
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/sample" }
                          route:
                            cluster: http4s_server_cluster
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder.v3.GrpcJsonTranscoder
                      proto_descriptor: "sample.proto"
                      services:
                        - proto_package: "com.proto"
                          proto_service: "SampleService"
                          json_name: "sample"
              use_remote_address: false
              access_log:
                - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
  clusters:
    - name: http4s_server_cluster
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: http4s_server_cluster
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: 127.0.0.1
                      port_value: 8081 # Assuming the HTTP4s server is running on localhost:8081
```

When I run
`envoy --config-path envoy_bridge.yaml`

I am getting this error

```
[source/server/server.cc:997] exiting
Unable to parse JSON as proto (INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid JSON in envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap @ static_resources.listeners[0].filter_chains[0].filters[0].typed_config.<any>.http_filters[0].typed_config.<any>.services[0]:  string, near  1:869 (offset  868): unexpected   character: '{'; expected '"'): {"static_resources":{"clusters":[{"connect_timeout":"0.25s","http2_protocol_options":{},"lb_policy":"round_robin","name":"http4s_server_cluster","load_assignment":{"cluster_name":"http4s_server_cluster","endpoints":[{"lb_endpoints":[{"endpoint":{"address":{"socket_address":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port_value":8081}}}}]}]},"type":"strict_dns"}],"listeners":[{"name":"listener_0","filter_chains":[{"filters":[{"name":"envoy.http_connection_manager","access_log":[{"name":"envoy.access_loggers.stdout","typed_config":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog"}}],"use_remote_address":false,"typed_config":{"route_config":{"name":"local_route","virtual_hosts":[{"routes":[{"route":{"cluster":"http4s_server_cluster"},"match":{"prefix":"/sample"}}],"name":"backend","domains":["*"]}]},"http_filters":[{"typed_config":{"services":[{"json_name":"sample","proto_package":"com.proto","proto_service":"SampleService"}],"@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder.v3.GrpcJsonTranscoder","proto_descriptor":"sample.proto"},"name":"envoy.filters.http.grpc_json_transcoder"}],"codec_type":"auto","@type":"type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager","stat_prefix":"ingress_http"}}]}],"address":{"socket_address":{"address":"0.0.0.0","port_value":8080}}}]}}
```

Comment: I double-triple checked indentation

Comment: To confirm [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) converts from REST|JSON clients to gRPC servers (not from gRPC clients)

Comment: You have `proto_descriptor: "sample.proto"` which is incorrect. This must be a proto descriptor which is a result of proto compilation.

Comment: @dazwilkin thanks for answer. I also thought grpc-json transcoder works from rest client to grpc server. 

So now I am using [reverse_bridge filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_http1_reverse_bridge_filter). 

Sorry this is my first time, but wondering what set up I need in my REST server in scala that accepts request from grpc client with .proto type body through envoy with reverse_bridge filtration?

I am able to run envoy, and REST server is listening, but when I run my grpc client I am getting UNIMPLEMENTED error

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the reverse bridge. I encourage you to submit a new question.